# flex item if wrap will squeeze another flex item space which is fix width

Tags: css, flexbox

```
demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1nogrctj/
```

you can see '50' in the second line is not enough 50px because the next flex item is wrap!

if the next flex item is no warp, the '50' get the right width.

So how to avoid it?

Comment: Is this the right demo? I don't see any wrapping.

Comment: the right demo is  https://jsfiddle.net/1nogrctj/1/

Answer (score 1):

I find the correct answer, as the fix width item need an attribute: 'flex-shrink: 0'.